# pop-up loading again and again in dashboard page

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

My purpose is when a user order a product need to get a notification in the dashboard page. Now the  notification is getting . when i click Ok, let me check button in the dashboard its go to  order listing page. but the problem is when i back to the dash baord the same order notication will coming. i need once i click,  when i click Ok, let me check button the same order pop-up will not show

my Ajax

```
<script>
 setInterval(function () {
 $.get({
        url: '{{route('get-order-data')}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            let data = response.data;
            if (data.new_order > 0) {
                playAudio();
                $('#popup-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
            }
        },
    });
 }, 1000);

function check_order() {
    location.href = '{{route('admin-order-pending')}}';
}
```

Function in Laravel

```
 public function order_data()
{
    $new_order = DB::table('orders')->where(['checked' => 0])->count();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 1,
        'data' => ['new_order' => $new_order]
    ]);
}
```

Pop-up code in dashboard

```
<div class="modal" id="popup-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <center>
                        <h2 style="color: rgba(96,96,96,0.68)">
                            <i class="tio-shopping-cart-outlined"></i> You have new order, Check Please.
                        </h2>
                        <hr>
                        <button onclick="check_order()" class="btn btn-primary">Ok, let me check</button>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, how are you updating the field in the database to show that the order has already been checked? Without doing that, the query will just keep returning the same rows.

Comment: BTW, bashing your server every second with an ajax request is really inefficient. Better to use websockets or server-sent events

Comment: @ADyson
 in my database checked will be zero for all

Comment: OK. But I assume that once you've checked each one you want to change that value so your query doesn't keep showing it?? If not then you'll need to explain the situation more clearly

Comment: ADyson when the customer order time the checked value in the db in the 0 status. the pop-up will come when i click on the  <button onclick="check_order()" class="btn btn-primary">Ok, let me check</button> the status need to change to 1 how i can do

Comment: By using a sql query obviously. And you can send an ajax request from the browser (using javascript) to trigger it. But clearly you need to know which order ID to update, so the database updates the correct row. Right now though, from what you've shown, you simply return a count of new orders. At what point does the system fetch and display a specific one?

Comment: @Adyson can you help while i share the code in your mail

Comment: You can share everything here by editing your question, then everyone can help - and everyone can benefit. That's why I help for free on stackoverflow, because it benefits the whole community.  I doubt you want to pay my hourly rates for private consultancy :-)

Comment: @ Adyson how i can slove this?

Comment: I just gave you the outline solution already. Can't be more specific without seeing where you select and display a new order

Answer (score -2):

```
 try this..  

  <script>
     setInterval(function () {
     $.get({
            url: '{{route('get-order-data')}}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                let data = response.data;
                if (data.new_order > 0) {
                    playAudio();
                    $('#popup-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
                }
 $('#popup-modal').appendTo("body").modal('none');
            },
        });
     }, 1000);
    
    function check_order() {
        location.href = '{{route('admin-order-pending')}}';
    }
    Function in Laravel
     public function order_data()
    {
        $new_order = DB::table('orders')->where(['checked' => 0])->count();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 1,
            'data' => ['new_order' => $new_order]
        ]);
    }
    Pop-up code in dashboard
    
    <div class="modal" id="popup-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <center>
                            <h2 style="color: rgba(96,96,96,0.68)">
                                <i class="tio-shopping-cart-outlined"></i> You have new order, Check Please.
                            </h2>
                            <hr>
                            <button onclick="check_order()" class="btn btn-primary">Ok, let me check</button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).